# Multithreaded Client Server Proxy java

Tags: java, network-programming

I am currently implementing a multithreaded proxy server in java which will accept messages from clients and forward them to another server which will then acknowledge the reception of the message. However, i'm having trouble doing so. Could someone point out what i am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Socket client = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 6789);
        if(client.isBound())
        {
            System.out.println("Successfully connected on port 6789");
        }
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        DataInputStream inFromProxy = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream outToProxy = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        while(true)
        {
             String message;
                System.out.print("Enter your message: ");
                message = scanner.next();
                outToProxy.writeUTF(message);
                System.out.println(inFromProxy.readUTF());
        }
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        System.err.println("IOException: " + io.getMessage());
        System.exit(2);
    }
    }
}
```

The server code Server.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

/** 
 *  the client send a String to the server the server returns it in UPPERCASE thats all
 */

public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6780);
        if(server.isBound())
        {
            System.out.println("Server successfully connected on port 6780");
        }
        Socket client = null;
        while(true)
        {
            client = server.accept();
            if(client.isConnected())
            {
                System.out.println("Proxy is connected");
            }

            DataInputStream inFromProxy = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outToProxy = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println(inFromProxy.readUTF());
            outToProxy.writeUTF("Message has been acknowledged!");
        }
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        System.err.println("IOException: " + io.getMessage());
        System.exit(2);
    }
}
}   




import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;

public class Proxy{

    public static ServerSocket server = null;

    public static Socket client = null;


public static void main(String[] args)
{
try
{
    server = new ServerSocket(6789);
    Socket clientsocket = null;

    while(true)
    {
        client = server.accept();      

        if(client.isConnected())
        {
            System.out.println("Proxy is currently listening to client on port 6789");
        }
        clientsocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 6780);
        Thread t1 = new ProxyHandler(client, clientsocket);
        t1.start();


        if(clientsocket.isBound())
        {
            System.out.println("Clientsocket successfully connected on port 6780");
        }

        Thread t2 = new ProxyHandler(clientsocket, client);
        t2.start();                                                               

    }
}
catch(IOException io)
{
    System.err.println("IOException: " + io.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

The Proxy code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ProxyHandler extends Thread {
private Socket socket;
private String message;
public ProxyHandler(Socket socket, Socket clientsocket)
{
    this.socket = socket;        
}

public void run()
{       
    message = "";
    try
    {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        while(true)
        {
            message = in.readUTF();
            out.writeUTF(message);

            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        System.err.println("IOException: " + io.getMessage());
        System.exit(2);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The client is not responding correctly, can you tell me where i am wrong

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: My output is as follows:

Server successfully connected on port 6780
Proxy is connected

But what I was trying to do was that Client Sending a message to the Server Via a proxy but that is not happening

Answer (score 1):

- There is no multithreading here. There should be. Each accepted socket should be entirely processed in its own thread, in both the server and the proxy.
- There is no point in testing isBound() immediately after creating and connecting a Socket. It will never be false.
- There is no point in testing isConnected() immediately after an accept(). It will never be false.
- The server must close each accepted socket once it is finished with it, i.e. once it has EOS from it (read() returns -1).
- The proxy must also close each accepted socket once it is finished with it, ditto.
- A proxy of any kind should just copy bytes. It shouldn't make assumptions about the format of the data. Don't use readUTF(), use count = read(byte[]) and write(buffer, 0, count). That also means that you don't need DataInput/OutputStreams in the proxy.